Unable to generate raster mbtiles for higher zoom levels
Starting with the Natural Earth Shaded Relief (medium size)
$ gdalinfo NE2_LR_LC_SR.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: NE2_LR_LC_SR.tif
       NE2_LR_LC_SR.tif.aux.xml
Size is 16200, 8100
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    …

$ gdal_translate NE2_LR_LC_SR.tif output.mbtiles -of MBTILES
Input file size is 16200, 8100
ERROR 1: PROJ: webmerc: Invalid latitude
412-3 more lines of errors
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

What's with those ERROR 1: PROJ: webmerc: Invalid latitude messages?
$ gdaladdo -r average output.mbtiles 2 4 8 16
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

$ gdalinfo output.mbtiles
Driver: MBTiles/MBTiles
Files: output.mbtiles
Size is 8192, 8192
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    …
Metadata:
  ZOOM_LEVEL=5
  …

So I tried again, this time specifying an explicit zoom level
$ gdal_translate -co ZOOM_LEVEL=10 -co FORMAT=webp -of MBTILES NE2_LR_LC_SR.tif output.mbtiles

But, got the same max zoom of 5 in the output. So I tried the same approach with the higher resolution tiff, the Natural Earth Shaded Relief (large size), but again, the max zoom level went up to 6 only, not 10 as I requested
$ gdal_translate -co ZOOM_LEVEL=10 -co FORMAT=webp -of MBTILES NE2_HR_LC_SR.tif output.mbtiles

$ gdalinfo output.mbtiles
Driver: MBTiles/MBTiles
Files: output.mbtiles
Size is 16383, 16384
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
…
Metadata:
  ZOOM_LEVEL=6
  …

Update: So, I learned that the MBTILES driver does not support specifying ZOOM_LEVELs, and gdal_translate determines the most appropriate highest zoom level for the given input. So, most of my query above irrelevant. But, the following questions still stand --
So, my questions are:

How do I generate higher zoom level tiles or, if Natural Earth not a suitable source for zoom levels higher than 6, are there other free sources of raster data at higher zooms?
And, if I don't or can't, how/what do I display when a user zooms in to more than 6?

In fact, it is clear that I don't want to precalculate tiles at high zoom levels because they will be just too many, and not often requested. But, if a user zooms in and wants to see more detail, I have to send back something other than a blank canvas. How do I generate the tiles on request and in a performant way?

The right thing would be to do that on the client side. Take the tiles at the highest available zoom level and stretch them (overzoom). What is your client?

I am using Leaflet. Do you have any pointers on how to "overzoom" the highest available zoom level in my cache?

Perhaps with maxNativeZoom https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18687120/leaflet-zoom-in-further-and-stretch-tiles

ok, that worked, and yes, the maps looked horrible 2 levels beyond the native zoom (the real zoom in my db). I am surprised Natural Earth tiles go only to level 6, even the ones listed as highest res.

The resolution of the medium size dataset is 0.022 degrees/pixel, so 256 pixels make 5.632 degrees, which is the native resolution at zoom level 6 https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels. With the HR version the size of the tile is 4.26752 degrees that is between levels 6 and 7. For higher zoom levels, acquire rasters with better resolution.  About the error message, the dataset covers also the poles, but the coordinate system of the MBTiles (EPSG:3857) is valid only between that latitude range -85 - +85 degrees https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3857/.
